# Android: in AsyncTask.doInBackground, loop is forcibly broken

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
public void start(final int timeInMS){
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> timer = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            long timeWhenStart = System.nanoTime();
            long now;
            do {
                now = System.nanoTime();
            } while ((now - timeWhenStart) < (timeInMS * 1000000));

            System.out.println((now - timeWhenStart) < (timeInMS * 1000000));
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            IntensityArc.this.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    };

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        timer.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, (Void[]) null);
    } else {
        timer.execute((Void[]) null);
    }
}
```

The output of this code is : false

The program should jump out of the loop when the condition is not satisfied. But the value of `(now - timeWhenStart)` was around 1,400,000,000 while the value of `(timeInMS * 1000000)` was 10,000,000,000, when the program stopped. The condition is obviously still satisfied. How can this be?

I use this timer to make the custom view disappear when time runs out.

P.S. I tried this time to make a class that extends the `AsyncTask` class, so it is no longer anonymous. And this time it worked. I don't understand why.

Comment: I printed the (now - timeWhenStart), it's always around 1,400,000,000 when the loop is broken. While my (timeInMS*1000000) is 10,000,000,000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cycle repeat **while the condition is true**.
So the cycle ends when the condition is **false** and your print it.

EDIT after updated question:

timeInMS is int, max value of int is 2 147 483 647.
If time timeInMS is 10 000, than 10 000 * 1 000 000 is more than a max value of the int.
As it doesn't fit into 32 bit, result int is 1 410 065 408.

You can make it long by multiplying long value.

```
long timeInNs = timeInMS * 1000000L;
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was stupid. I'll change the question description.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I checked, it worked after I made a new AsyncTask class only because I changed the condition to '(int) ((now - timeWhenStar)/1000000) < timeInMS'.

Answer (score 1):

Use long data type instead of all integer values.
If using numaric value then use like : 100000L